# Moment js returns invalid date after format

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, momentjs

I have the following code in my application :

```js
moment(dateD, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

The `dateD` is like this `2020-05-30 00:00:00.0` i want to parse it to this Format `DD/MM/YYYY` but the problem my code returns Invalid Date.

Comment: Try without Passing second argument to moment i.e YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2020-05-30 00:00:00.0` can't be parsed with the format string `YYYY-MM-DD` (the time is missing).

Simplest solution for your case would be:

```
moment(dateD.split(" ")[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Or the OP could include the time in the input format string. ;-)